# INSERT Conflict on Virtual Table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, insert

I am having a problem on the INSERT because of a FK reference. The process goes like this:

1. I create the table `Cuentas`, and `Cuentas_Con_RowNumber`
2. I select from a huge table with over 3 million records. Because some are repeated and I need to store only 1 "cuenta", I made the `tempDB`. I have to do this, because on the huge db there are many records with the same `Cuenta_Nro` with different transactions, and I just need one.
3. I select from the `tempDB` all the columns but the `RowNumber` and then insert it into the `Cuentas` table.
4. The problem is that the `tempDB` `Pais` (country) column is not a FK which references to the `Paises` (countries) table, and on the original table (`Cuentas`) it does, therefore, it crashes.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Paises 
(
    Pais_Id numeric(18,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Pais_Nombre varchar(255) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Cuentas 
(
    Cuenta_Nro numeric(18,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Cuenta_Estado varchar(255),
    Cuenta_Moneda varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Dolar',
    Cuenta_Tipo numeric(18,0) 
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tipo_De_Cuentas(Tipo_De_Cuenta_Id),
    Cuenta_PaisOrigen numeric(18, 0) 
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Paises(Pais_Id),
    Cuenta_PaisAsignado numeric(18, 0) 
       FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Paises(Pais_Id),
    Cuenta_Fec_Cre datetime,
    Cuenta_Fec_Cierre datetime,
    Cuenta_Tarjeta numeric(18, 0) 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tarjetas(Tarjeta_Nro),
    Cuenta_Cliente numeric(18, 0) 
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Clientes(Cliente_Id)
)

CREATE TABLE #Cuentas_Con_RowNumer
(
    Cuenta_Nro numeric(18,0) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    Cuenta_Estado varchar(255),
    Cuenta_PaisOrigen numeric(18,0)),
    Cuenta_Fec_Cre datetime, 
    Cuenta_Fec_Cierre datetime, 
    Cuenta_Cliente numeric(18,0), 
    Cuenta_Tarjeta numeric(18,0), 
    RowNumber int
)

INSERT INTO #Cuentas_Con_RowNumer
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT 
            Maestro.Cuenta_Numero, Maestro.Cuenta_Estado, Maestro.Cuenta_Pais_Codigo, 
            Maestro.Cuenta_Fecha_Creacion, Maestro.Cuenta_Fecha_Cierre, Clientes.Cliente_Id, Maestro.Tarjeta_Numero,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Maestro.Cuenta_Numero ORDER BY Maestro.Cuenta_Numero) AS RowNumber
        FROM gd_esquema.Maestra Maestro, dbo.Clientes
        WHERE 
        Clientes.Cliente_Apellido = Maestro.Cli_Apellido AND
        Clientes.Cliente_Nombre = Maestro.Cli_Nombre) AS a
    WHERE a.RowNumber = '1'


INSERT INTO Cuentas  
    (
        Cuenta_Nro, Cuenta_Estado, Cuenta_PaisOrigen, Cuenta_Fec_Cre, 
        Cuenta_Fec_Cierre, Cuenta_Cliente, Cuenta_Tarjeta
    )
    SELECT 
        Cuenta_Nro, Cuenta_Estado, Cuenta_PaisOrigen, Cuenta_Fec_Cre, 
        Cuenta_Fec_Cierre, Cuenta_Cliente, Cuenta_Tarjeta
    FROM #Cuentas_Con_RowNumer
```

The error message is:

> Instrucción INSERT en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "FK__Cuentas__Cuenta___24B338F0". El conflicto ha aparecido en la base de datos "GD1C2015", tabla "dbo.Paises", column 'Pais_Id'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `Maestro.Cuenta_Pais_Codigo` column is being pulled from `gd_esquema.Maestra` table which in turn is going as `Cuenta_PaisOrigen` in target table and has a foreign key defined.

There will be some records which are being selected for insert `Cuentas` table that doesn't have a matching `Pais_Id` record in `dbo.Paises` table.

You can add a inner join as below and check the results as :

```
INSERT INTO #Cuentas_Con_RowNumer
    SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT 
            ...
        FROM gd_esquema.Maestra Maestro 
        inner join dbo.Clientes on      
        Clientes.Cliente_Apellido = Maestro.Cli_Apellido AND
        Clientes.Cliente_Nombre = Maestro.Cli_Nombre
        inner join Paises P on Maestro.Cuenta_Pais_Codigo = P.Pais_Id
        ) AS a
    WHERE a.RowNumber = '1'
```